# converging average of loop?

Tags: sequences-and-series, average, programming

I ran the following script, It starts with a random number, then takes it's reciprocal and gets it's fractional part, Then it repeats it again, and takes average.

```
var x = Math.random();
var i = 0;
var k = 0;
var n; //number of iterations

while (i<n) {
x = (1/x)%1;
k+=x;
i++;
}

console.log(k/n);
```

The outputs where as follows

when n=100, output=`0.45473379363722793`
when n=1000, output=`0.4517287948011644`
when n=10000, output=`0.4411420299062774`
when n=100000, output=`0.4423720018398649`
when n=1000000, output=`0.4423947214693864`
when n=10000000, output=`0.442541609651593`

Thus the output seems to converge around something like `0.442..`

Is there a method to find the average for infinite iterations (theoretically)?

Is there any significance of that number?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khinchin%27s_constant . Your limit seems to be $\int_0^1x/(1+x)dx/\log2$.

Comment: @kimchi-lover Thank you, I will see that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The limit is the mean of the invariant probability measure on $[0,1]$ for the Gauss map
$x \mapsto 1/x - \lfloor 1/x \rfloor$.  That invariant measure has density $\dfrac{1}{\ln(2)(1+x)}$, and mean $\dfrac{1}{\ln(2)}-1 \approx 0.4426950409$.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't knew that